# PHP backend sometimes return status code 500 with HTML, how can my react front end handle this?

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm currently using AXIOS in React to make API requests, but I ran into a problem. The API provider usually returns JSON in 2xx or 404, but other times it returns HTML error pages which makes my JSON error handling not work. It's completely random to me as the front end, as I don't know which ones return what unless I go through and test each API with faulty requests (I assume this is the backends job and document it but they won't do it so it's up to me).

I have talked to my coworker who is writing the API, but they told me they can't turn those into JSON and have to keep it as HTML as some limitations with an older PHP backend. So now I have to handle both JSON and HTML error, however, they don't tell me which ones are JSON and which is HTML. Also, I cannot read the HTML and know for sure what the error message is so I can only give a general error: ie. Resource not found. Now they told me they want to display the actual error message for debug reasons, which I can't get through HTML (or at least I don't think I can)

Is the best option for me to write in my interceptor to detect each time a status code 4xx - 5xx comes in is HTML or not? Then put it in a custom error object and assign a type so I can later tell if it's HTML or not?

I have never dealt with a whole suite of APIs that returns 2 types of error, being JSON and HTML. I wonder if anyone have dealt with it to shed some light on this.

Comment: Is there no consistency at all? e.g. all 500s are HTML, or something like that? If you detect an error status, then yes you may need to check the data type before you attempt to process it. The response header will hopefully have the correct content type set. If the error HTML is in a consistent structure, you could probably parse it to find where the relevant error message is...but yeah that's a massive PITA. We had this issue with an old API in my organisation, and we got rid of the HTML errors. I find it hard to believe they really can't get rid of them if they try hard enough.

Comment: @ADyson My bet is they are not trying, cause at the end of the day, application crashes or data not showing up would be my fault if not handled correctly, nobody would look at the error message other than me. The HTML error page is massive, I really didn't want to use additional resources to parse it as the internal application I'm working on already has a massive amount of data and manipulations. At this point, I'm just inclined to show a modal style popup for these errors and just display the entire error if they really want see debug code...

Answer (score 2):

Response, even an error response, should contain `Content-Type` header which in your case should be either `application/json` for JSON responses and `text/html` for HTML responses. You should always only JSON-decode responses with `application/json` content type. Actually axios will do that for you if a proper content type header is present on the response.

There's a chance though that your API is returning JSON with `text/html` content type. If that happens, you have to have some serious discussion with your backend developers and strongly insist on having proper `Content-Type` on all API responses.

Comment: Yeah, it's the server-side. I have no control whatsoever. I have talked to them at least 4 times, and all I got back was nothing we can do. This issue has persisted with the swift/android native applications I have worked on in the company as well, but again I never found a good solution to this, it just always felt hacky and I'm pretty sure it's hacky...react is much more tolerable but native apps would just crash unless I do addtional handling.